# How to adjust colors of eslint markings / bracket matches in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I use a very small bitmap font for coding.
when i type, eslint & brackets constantly flash with their highlighting.
it's impossible to type comfortably due this problem.
how can i change colors of the highlighting?
(i would set some transparency).
or at least turn them off?

eslint markings & bracket matchings example with BIG font

[image: 1]

Comment: Please postt he code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found, this allows to set the color of the wavy line in `settings.json`:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground": "#0000",
    },
```